# Can anyone identify this North Texas weed?

Tags: identification, weeds

I recently moved into a house in north Texas (DFW area) from an apartment in the same area. I had 3 potted pepper plants (jalapeno and serrano) that had died about 4 years ago. I planted them in miracle grow soil (if that helps at all), but my neighbor above me at my old apartment had a dog that constantly urinated on the balcony and it dripped down onto my plants, so I gave up on them for the time being. Now I'm in my new house and I was surprised and excited to see one of my pepper plants sprouting back up after quite a few rains. However, next to it is this interesting looking weed that I've not seen before anywhere in my yard or my neighbors yards. I'm dying to know what it is so I can pull it out already. So far no flowers have appeared.

The first 3 pictures are from May 10th and the next 2 are from May 28th. The weed is growing much much faster than my pepper plant.. The weed is not spikey, it actually feels kind of like fur on the main stem. The leaves are also not spikey, although they look like they might be. The last 2 pictures are of a leaf I picked off of it just now.

[image: 5-10]

[image: 5-10]

[image: 5-10]

[image: 5-28]

[image: 5-28]

[image: Top]
Top of leaf

[image: Bottom]
Bottom/back of leaf

I hope this was a good enough description, thanks for any help! :)

Answer (score 3):

Ok.. I figured it out, it is marestail (Conyza canadensis). At least that's what I was able to narrow it down to on Google.